# Direct Products in Coordinate Basis

Tags: quantum-mechanics

I am reading quantum mechanics by R. Shankar and I was confused about how he projected the state vector onto the two-state coordinate basis. Below is the part that he wrote

$\\$

> Since the notion of a direct product space is so important, we revisit the formation of $V_{1\otimes2}$ as a direct product of $V_1$ and $V_2$ , but this time in the coordinate basis instead of in the abstract. Let $\Omega^{(1)}_1$ be an operator on $V_1$ whose nondegenerate eigenfunctions $\psi_{\omega_1}(x_1) = \omega_1(x_1)$ form a complete basis. Similarly let $\omega_2(x_2)$ form a
>   basis for $V_2$. Consider now a function $\psi(x_1, x_2)$, which represents the abstract $\left|\psi\right\rangle$ from $V_{1\otimes2}$. If we keep $x_1$ fixed at some value, say $\bar{x}_1$, then $\psi$ becomes a function of $x_2$ alone and may be expanded as
>
> $$\psi(\bar{x}_1,x_2) = \Sigma_{\omega_2} C_{\omega_2}(\bar{x}_1) \omega_2(x_2) $$
>
> Notice that the coefficients of the expansion depend on the value of $\bar{x}_1$. We now expand the function $C_{\omega_2}(\bar{x}_1)$ in the basis $\omega_1(\bar{x}_1)$:
>
> $$C_{\omega_2}(\bar{x}_1) = \Sigma_{\omega_1} C_{\omega_1,\omega_2} \omega_1(\bar{x}_1)$$
>
> Feeding this back to the first expansion and dropping the bar on $\bar{x}_1$ we get
>
> $$\psi(x_1,x_2) = \Sigma_{\omega_1} \Sigma_{\omega_2} C_{\omega_1,\omega_2} \omega_1(x_1) \omega_2(x_2)$$

To my knowledge, he expanded $\left|\psi\right\rangle$ first in the $\left|\omega_2\right\rangle$ basis,

$$\left|\psi\right\rangle = \Sigma_{\omega_2} \left|\omega_2\right\rangle \left\langle\omega_2\right|\psi\rangle$$

then projected onto the coordinate basis $\left|x_1,x_2\right\rangle$

$$ \psi (\bar{x_1},x_2) = \langle \bar{x}_1,x_2 \rvert\psi\rangle = \Sigma_{\omega_2} \langle \bar{x}_1,x_2 \rvert\omega_2\rangle \langle\omega_2\rvert\psi\rangle = \Sigma_{\omega_2} \langle\omega_2\rvert\psi\rangle \langle \bar{x}_1,x_2 \rvert\omega_2\rangle = \Sigma_{\omega_2} C_{\omega_2} (\bar{x}_1) \omega_2(x_2)$$

where $C_{\omega_2} (\bar{x}_1) = \langle\omega_2\rvert\psi\rangle$ and $\omega_2(x_2) = \langle \bar{x}_1,x_2 \rvert\omega_2\rangle$

This is my first question, is my interpretation of the notations correct? That is, is it correct that $C_{\omega_2} (\bar{x}_1) = \langle\omega_2\rvert\psi\rangle$ and $\omega_2(x_2) = \langle \bar{x}_1,x_2 \rvert\omega_2\rangle$? In addition, why is $C_{\omega_2} (\bar{x}_1)$ a function of $\bar{x}_1$ given that it is $\langle\omega_2\rvert\psi\rangle$.

My second question is, how (in the sense of Dirac notation) to do the step by step expansion of a coefficient $C_{\omega_2} (\bar{x}_1)$ in terms of another basis $\omega_1(\bar{x}_1)$?